# Operação com varchar no SQL 2014

Tags: sql, sql-server

Estou tentando fazer uma conta de menos no sql sever management porém da esse erro de formato. Estou querendo fazer a conta de meses *202103* - *202101* = *2 meses*

Como resolver esse problema de formato?

```
select *
    ,DPD = datediff(day, Dt_Atraso, Dt_Ref)
    ,DIAS_Prazo = datediff(day, Dt_Abertura, Dt_Vencimento)
    **,DIFERENCA = (MES_ATUAL - MES_ATRASO)**
from #chuv_pJ
```

ERRO:

> ```
> Msg 402, Level 16, State 1, Line 4
> The data types varchar and varchar are incompatible in the subtract operator.
> ```

Comment: `datediff(day, Dt_Abertura, Dt_Vencimento)` se quer a diferença em meses, mude o `day` para `month`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

O problema é que está tentando realizar uma subtração de dois campos do tipo varchar.
Será necessário fazer uma `cast` antes. Esse `cast` vai considerar o valor como `date` para poder realizar o cálculo entre datas.
Antes de realizar o `cast`, sugiro concatenar com a `string` `+'01'` para gerar uma data válida conforme exemplo funcional abaixo:

```
    select *
        ,DPD = datediff(day, Dt_Atraso, Dt_Ref)
        ,DIAS_Prazo = datediff(day, Dt_Abertura, Dt_Vencimento)
        ,DIFERENCA = DATEDIFF(MONTH,cast(MES_ATRASO+'01' as date),cast(MES_ATUAL+'01' as date))
    from #chuv_pJ
```

Answer (score 0):

Conforme sugerido em comentário, pra ter a diferença entre duas datas em *meses*, você só precisa alterar o *"datepart"*, que é o primeiro parâmetro da função [`datediff()`](https://docs.microsoft.com/pt-br/sql/t-sql/functions/datediff-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15).

```
SELECT *,
    DPD = datediff(day, Dt_Atraso, Dt_Ref),
    DIAS_Prazo = datediff(day, Dt_Abertura, Dt_Vencimento),
    DIFERENCA = datediff(month, Dt_Abertura, Dt_Vencimento)
FROM #chuv_pJ
```

Comment: O problema é que a variavel MES_ATUAL e MES_ATRASO não está em formato de data, ela era data e foi transformada em texto, quando tento utilizar o datadiff aparece o seguinte erro: Msg 241, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string.  eu consigo transformar essa variavel novamente em data?